# Use Custom terminal for Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, pyinstaller, windows-terminal

It seems `Pyinstaller` on Windows use `cmd.exe` alike terminal for the executable outputs. However the `CMD` is pretty bad at handling `Unicode` and `ANSI` commands [like color codes, console tricks]
However the `Windows terminal` does a real great job on it. So is there any way to Embed [not sure this is the right word] the `wt.exe` inside the Pyinstaller Executable file to handle the program like it's running on `windows terminal`

*did some ground works to run `ANSI` commands. but still stuck at the unicode part*

Comment: I think `PyInstaller` has nothing to do - it sends it to system and system decide what terminal to use.

Comment: well then, is there any way to use uncode fonts (that `wt` use) and make it more emoji and unicode compatitable. Don't know how to chance terminal default font by script (also don't like the colosus font)

Comment: it is rather not font but encoding. As I know Windows terminal may use encoding CP1250 and there was somewhere method to change it with `Register` - probably using encoding `60000`

Comment: [Change default code page of Windows console to UTF-8](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8)

Comment: I don't use Windows for years and I can't help more.

Comment: Appreciate your help, diving deep in the encoding stuffs

Comment: neither `60000` & `1250` as you mentioned nor `65001` in the question worked for me to display ``. checking if i can get more info on it